# Как сделать плавающий блок замирающий под header?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

У меня есть `header` который закреплен к верху страницы

```
position: fixed;
 z-index: 1000;
```

И так же есть блок в середине страницы. Нужно чтобы он, когда до него "докручивался" `header` тоже становился `fixed`. Т. е. под `header` этот блок, они `fixed`, а ниже дальше прокручивается контент.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
        $(window).scroll(function(){
            var bo = $("body").scrollTop();
        if ( bo > 1000 ) $(".block").css({position: 'fixed',left:'0px'});
        })

    })
```

```css
.header{
height:100px;
width:100%;
position: fixed;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color: red;}
.content{
height:500px;
width:100%;
top:0px;
left:0px;
background-color:blue;}
.block{
height:100px;
width:100%;
background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="header">Position:Fixed<div>
<div class="content"><div>
<div class="block"><div>
<div class="content"><div>
```

Comment: спасибо. Подскажите пожалуйста, почему у меня значение $('body').scrollTop() всегда равно 0. Даже при прокрутке?

Answer (score 1):

Есть плагин jquery для sticky.

```js
$("[data-sticky]").sticky();
```

```css
section {
height:120vh;
background:green;
}
header {
background:red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery.sticky/1.0.4/jquery.sticky.min.js"></script>
<section role="banner">

</section>
<header data-sticky="true">
text
</header>
<section role="banner"></section>
```

Answer (score 0):

вот пример на чистом css TOP задай под высоту header

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 1000px;
}

div {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  background-color: #0D4585;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  margin-top: 330px;
}
```

```html
<div></div>
```